# Showing the output from ajax response on a particular frame

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

My html page is divided into various frameset and frames.

[This is the image of the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyHow.jpg)

The frame displaying basic(loops) and advance (oops) is called (has name) as output.

When clicking on OOPS its is received in javascript and an ajax call is made to php to get an iframe (there will be many such links under oops later).

"once the iframe is received i would like to know how to display it on the frame named output." i.e.;

1. should there be href attribute in below html anchor tag if yes where it should redirect (I would like to know how to display it on the frame named output).
2. what to do in the javascript file after receiving the data from php (getting ajax response).

This frame named output is declared (made) in the very first file while creating this UI and all other frames have their target attribute as output frame.

Let me know if any other information is needed.

//html

```
            <html>
            <head>
                <script type = "text/javascript" src = "validate.js">
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <center>
                    <h2> Advance </h2>
                    <a href = "" id = "o1" target = "output" onclick = 
      "find(this.id)"> OOPS </a>
                </center>
            </body>
        </html>
```

// js file

```
              var request;

         function find(id) 
         {
           var url = "output.php?video=" + id;
           var method = "GET";

               if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
               {
                 request = new XMLHttpRequest();
               } 

               else if (window.ActiveXObject)
               {
                 request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
               } 

           request.open(method, url, true);
           request.send(null);
           request.onreadystatechange = getInfo;  

         }  

         function getInfo() 
         {
           if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
           {
             var val = request.responseText;
            //what would come here.
           }
         }
```

//php file

```
            <?php

            $o = $_GET['video'];
            switch($o)
            {
                case "o1":
                    echo '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" 
           src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dD2EISBDjWM" frameborder="0" 
           allowfullscreen></iframe>'
                    break;
            }

        ?>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset frames and framesets are deprecated. I'd advise you not to use them in anything new. You can get just the same kind of effect much more simply and flexibly by using divs and CSS.

Comment: If you aren't familiar with it at all in any way, to be honest you would better off taking some kind of up-to-date tutorial about HTML and CSS which shows how to create a layout with multiple columns. You'd learn more than if I just give you a random sample with no detailed explanation.